# No permission to modify static procedure `(-)/1'

Tags: prolog

When i do an assert like:

```
assert(-color(red)).
```

it gives me the error:

```
ERROR: assert/1: No permission to modify static procedure `(-)/1'
```

so i change -color to dynamic:

```
dynamic -color/4.
```

and now it gives me the error:

```
ERROR: dynamic/1: Type error: `atom' expected, found `-color'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, as Prolog itself is telling you, it is reading `-color(foo)` as `-(color(foo))`. That's why it's complaining about `(-)/1` and not `-color`. You cannot begin an atom with a hyphen.

Second, you want `asserta/1` or `assertz/1`, not `assert/1`.

Third, when you declare a dynamic predicate with arity 4, you should use it with arity 4, not arity 1. In other words, your dynamic should either read `:- dynamic color/4` and be used `asserta(color(Red,Green,Blue,Alpha))` or it should read `:- dynamic color/1` and be used `asserta(color(red))`. The combination `/4` with `/1` is not what you mean.