# Unable to make facts dynamic in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

I would like to be able to retract and assert facts dynamically for the procedure `location`:

```
location(egg, duck_pen).
```

Based on advice online (including [No permission to modify static procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284177/no-permission-to-modify-static-procedure)), I've tried adding each of the following to my source code, which otherwise contains only the above assertion:

```
dynamic location/2.
dynamic(location/2).
dynamic(location)/2.
```

The first two versions give me this error at compile-time (when loaded into SWI-Prolog):

```
No permission to redefine built-in predicate `(dynamic)/1'
Use :- redefine_system_predicate(+Head) if redefinition is intended
```

The last version does not give me an error at compile-time, but, whether I put it at the beginning or end of the file, I get an error when I try retracting my fact:

```
?- retract(location(egg,duck_pen)).
ERROR: retract/1: No permission to modify static procedure `location/2'
```

I am using SWI-Prolog version 6.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
:- dynamic location/2.

location(X, Y) blah blah
```