# SWI-Prolog No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'

Tags: prolog

This question has been asked quite a lot (for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360628/swi-prolog-swish-no-permission-to-modify-static-procedure-2)) but I could not understand why it's happening and how to fix it.

I want to make a list `Z` and count its elements. This is my code:

```
Z = [a,b,c,d,e].

listlength([],0).
listlength([Head|Tail],Count):-
    listlength(Tail,PartialCount),
    Count is PartialCount + 1 .
```

But I get the following error (and warnings):

```
ex3.pl:1:   Warning:    Singleton variables: [Z]
ex3.pl:1:   ERROR:  No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'
ex3.pl:5:   Warning:    Singleton variables: [Head]
ex3.pl:5:   Warning:    Singleton variables: [Head]
```

I do not understand how I can fix it, and I do not know how to define a list and test the `listlength` rule. I'm using SWI-Prolog 7.6.4 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error.... *how*? doing *what*? I'm guessing, you are loading a file with the above definitions in it. Then each of them is interpreted as a *predicate* definition. In particular,

```
Z = [1,2,3].
```

is read as if it were

```
=(Z, [1,2,3]).
```

which is the same as

```
=(Z, [1,2,3]) :- true.
```

and that means you *are* redefining the built-in predicate `=/2`.

Instead, define

```
mypred([1,2,3]).
```

and use it in queries like

```
?- mypred(Z), write(Z).
```

Answer (score 0):

At `listLength.pl` implement your facts:

```
listLength([],0).
listLength([_|Tail],Count):-            % Fixing Singleton variables: [Head] 
    listLength(Tail,PartialCount),      % Variable `Head` was not in use.
    Count is PartialCount + 1 .         % Use wildcard `_`

?- Z = [a,b,c,d,e], listLength(Z,5).    % For queries in files use `?-`
                                        % Fixing Singleton variables: [Z] and
                                        % No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'
```

After using `consult('listLength.pl').`

You can use `listLength/2` which you implemented:

```
?- listLength([1,3,4,2],X).
X = 4.

?- listLength([a,b,c,d,e],X).
X = 5.

?- Z=[1,3,a,b,3], listLength(Z,X).
Z = [1, 3, a, b, 3],
X = 5.
```

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. I was trying to add `Z=[...]` as a predicate.